# How to email a web page?

Tags: php, email

I've created a web page on my domain and I want to allow any visitor to send this page to anyone by email.

The page has a picture, css and php code. And it gets top 5 news from my site.

I'm trying to use this class:

```
<?php
include_once("../DataAccess.php");
class sendmail
{
    /**
     * @var from mail.
     */
    public $from = "kam@yahoo.com";

    /**
     * @var from name.
     */
    public $fromName = " Mail List";

    /**
     * @var to mail.
     */
    public $to  = 'eng.k@gmail.com'; // note the comma , if you want multiple recipients

    /**
     * @var to name.
     */
    public $name = 'Khaled';

    /**
     * @var subject.
     */
    public $subject = 'Hello World !!';

    /**
     * @var message.
     */
    public $message = 'Thank you, your message has been received We will reply you as soon eng@gmail.com';

    /**
     * @var newlines.
     */
    private $RN = "\r\n";

    /**
     * @var message charset.
     */
    public $charset = 'utf-8';

    /**
     * Sends an email.
     *
     * @author Yousef Ismaeil.
     */
    public function mail_to ()
    {

        $mail = &$this;

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$mail->RN;
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset='.$mail->charset.''.$mail->RN;
        // Additional headers
        $headers .= 'To: '.$mail->name.' <'.$mail->to.'>'.$mail->RN;
        $headers .= 'From: '.$mail->fromName.' <'.$mail->from.'>'.$mail->RN;
        $headers .= 'Return-Path: '.$mail->from.'\r\n';
        $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";



        if (@mail($mail->to, $mail->subject, $mail->message, $headers))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}

$date1=date('Y-m-d');
$send_mail = new sendmail();
$send_mail->from     = "zizo@yahoo.com";
$send_mail->fromName = "Zamalkawy Ana";
$send_mail->to       = "kam@ar.com";
$send_mail->name     = "Khlaed";
$send_mail->subject  = "Zamalkawy Ana Sports news for ".$date1;
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://zamalkawyana.com/MailList/home.php');
$send_mail->message  = $homepage;
if ($send_mail->mail_to()) echo 'Msg sent';
else echo 'Can\'t send msg.'; 

?>
```

... but when I send it, I only get a title and picture of news and cannot see the template of the page.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just so you know, if you send mail from an address such as yahoo, and it doesn't actually come from yahoo servers, it will probably be dropped (google DKIM and Sender Policy Framework for more information)

Comment: aim use email by Google but not send the temp on email

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what $homepage contains in the above explanation. It *might* be the html markup of your page. But it is questionable if you really want to send *that* content.

What is usually done instead is not to send the actual html content, but a link (the url) pointing to the page instead. Since your page can be reached by a url in the internet anyway this is a trivial step to do.

This has some advantages:

1. the message gets much smaller, since it is only a few lines of text plus the link. And it leaves the decision to visit the page or not to the receiver.
2. the message can be displayed in any email client without the huge security problems html messages hold. So it is more fair towards the receipients, since you don't have to ask ultimate trust from any receiver just to open a message from you.
3. you can write a few lines about what this message actually contains, why it is sent and so on. It is friendlier, since it is more transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the headers:  `$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

And you can put html code inside the message body (as string).

Also look at this [link](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

Comment: i will be used but not change yet

Comment: Indeed, I used your code from the beginning `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset='.$mail->charset.''.$mail->RN;` see my code

Comment: [link](http://up.top4top.net/uploads/2012/11/17/top4top_f3b26b374b1.jpg)